# Why NSCalendar date differ from NSDateComponents components date?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponent

ANy idea why this code output "2011-11-30 23:00:00 +0000" instead "2011-12-01 00:00:00 +0000"

```
NSDateComponents *minDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[minDateComponents setYear:2011];
[minDateComponents setMonth:12];
[minDateComponents setDay:1];
[minDateComponents setHour:00];
[minDateComponents setMinute:00];
[minDateComponents setSecond:0];
[minDateComponents setTimeZone:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:minDateComponents]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the NSDateComponent timeZone property to match your NSCalendar timeZone property. You could, for example, set them both to

```
[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```

or

```
[NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```